# Mapping two data sources with different table structures to one entity using JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following entity:

```
@Entity 
public class Product {

      @Id
      private Long id;

      @ManyToOne
      @JoinColumn(name = "vendorId", nullable = false)
      private Vendor vendor;   

     // other fields, setters and getters 
}
```

The application has its own database. It contains a `Product` table that is mapped to this entity. It also has a `Vendor` table that is mapped to the `Vendor` entity.

The application can also get `Product` and `Vendor` data from a 3rd party database. It can only read from the third party database. It gets the data from a single table called `ProdVendor`. The table is missing several fields included in the `Product` and `Vendor` entities. Additionally, the column names are different from the application's database. After getting the 3rd party data, the application will add some of the missing data points and then save the entities to the application's database.

Is there a way to use annotations to map the 3rd party DB table to these entities? Or is there some other way to do this besides creating a separate `ProdVendor` entity and writing code to map `ProdVendor` to `Product` and `Vendor` entities?

Comment: Do you use any ORM Frameworks?

Comment: I'm using Hibernate within the context of Spring Data JPA.

Comment: does `Vendor` class have a field of type `Product`?

Comment: No it does not.